# Handle notification callback - IOS

Tags: ios, callback, notifications

I have a notification triggered on press of a UIButton. The following is the code.

```
UILocalNotification* notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notif)
{
     notif.repeatInterval    = 0;
     notif.soundName         = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
     notif.alertAction       = NSLocalizedString(@"View", @"View");
     notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
     notif.alertBody = s;
     notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  presentLocalNotificationNow:notif];
}
```

Now, the notification is triggering. On click of notification I need to go to some other UIViewController. But currently, it redirects to the UIViewController from which it is called. Please direct how to accomplish the same.

Comment: could you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 2):

You must manage didReceiveLocalNotification and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions methods in AppDelegate.m file like below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if(localNotif) {
         ...

    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
{
    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog(@"app not running");
    }
    else if(app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        NSLog(@"app running");
    }

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;

    YourViewController *yourVC = ... ;

    [navController presentViewController:yourVC animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: perfect, one small thing, if i want to open a uiviewcontroller here instead of logging, how can i do that? (Need not be connected with segue), since its from delegate class